# Maven works strange when Intellij upgrade from Intellij 11 to Intellij14

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, resources, pom.xml, intellij-14

I configure my properties file in pom as bellow:

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>properties/*.properties</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
</resources>
```

When I open the project with Intellij 11 and rebuild project.
All properties files in the path

> src/main/resources/properties/

are compiled into the target/classed/properties.
That seems:

```
<excludes>
    <exclude>properties/*.properties</exclude>
</excludes>
```

in pom.xml doesn't work.

But when I open the project with Intellij 14,it seems work.

In fact what I want is:
Open it with Intellij 14,and rebuild project,all properties files should be compiled into  the target/classes path, so that I can run server correctly in IDE.
But also I hope all properties should be excluded when run maven independent for on jenkins build.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the two IDEs check your Maven home directory configuration under `File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Maven` in both versions to ensure the same Maven Version/ Installation is in usage and exclude the possibility it does not have anything to do with the IDE at all.

Regardless of the two IDE versions i would consider the output of your build triggered from within Intellij 11 wrong since the exclude-rule is ignored.

Generally when you want to include everything but certain files in the exclude-rule i would not explicitly include everything (`<include>**/*</include>`) at first to then exclude the files but have only the exclusion. The documentation is not very clear on possible effects this mix might bring up using different Maven versions or build parameters.

**Relevant documentation:** http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html

When it comes to having the *.propertie files beeing included locally but excluded on Jenkins you would want to have **seperated build profiles for both environments** (local/ remote[Jenkins]).

**Relevant documentation:** http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

I recomend to quickly read the above documentation of build profiles, they are easy to use and there are certain possibilities to trigger different profiles (for example based on system-properties, system OS or a command line argument explicitly activating a certain profile) which is the correct way to exclude files in one environments build while in another environment those properties are not excluded during the build.

Comment: First I explained why I want *.properties files included on local but excluded on Jenkins.
These properties files(database.properties,application.properties etc.),their content are different for developers.But on production server,I put them in the path `code`${catalina.home}/shared`code`.
So they are excluded from ROOT.war(built on jenkins).

Comment: @fcbflying sorry for the missunderstanding. I dont want to imply it makes no sence to have this scenario or something in that direction (we use it ourselves) - i edit the question because the motivation its relativly indifferent and doesnt change anything about the correct solution to use build profiles :)

Comment: So the solution?
For current now, my guys have to copy *.properties files into the path `target/classes/properties` manually.
That is not a good way.